# 単一の画像付きツイートの画像サイズについて

Tags: twitter

**Q1.600×335の比率を計算すると、16:9にならないのですが、どういう意味ですか？**

> 画像サイズ: 横600×縦335ピクセル以上 
>   縦横比: 横16:縦9
>   [単一の画像付きツイートおよびGIF画像](https://business.twitter.com/ja/help/campaign-setup/advertiser-card-specifications.html)

---

**Q2.上記リンク先の(翻訳前)原文ページを確認する方法はありますか？**
jaをenへ変更しても、リダイレクトされてしまいます
https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-setup/advertiser-card-specifications.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1. あくまで「以上」の推奨値なので、16:9ぴったりである必要は無いのではないでしょうか (モバイル端末を意識した値と書いてありますよね)。

A2. ページを開いたフッタ(最下段)に「言語」というメニューがあるので、ここからEnglishを選択すれば切り替わります。